# CSS Help for a project. Page needs to have a 'form' element that is 600px when the window is wider than 600px and

Tags: html, css, media-queries

CSS Help for a project.  Page needs to have a 'form' element that is 600px when the window is wider than 600px and is the width of the screen when the screen is less than 600px wide.

It seems to work when the screen is more that 600px, but will not stay the width of the screen when the screen shrinks below 600px.

```css
.card {
  height: 335px;
  width: 344px;
  border: lightgrey;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  transition: box-shadow;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.card-body {
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #232f34;
}

.card_image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 194px;
}

.person {
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}

.title {
  display: inline;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 16px;
}

.secondary {
  color: #232f34;
  display: inline;
  padding: 16px;
}
.myform {
  max-width: 600px;
}

@media screen {
  nav {
    position: static;
    height: auto;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  form {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 600px;
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="/pets">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input name="pet_name" id="name" type="text" />
  <br>
  <label for="type">Type</label>
  <select name="pet_type" id="type">
    <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="Hamster">Hamster</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
    <option value="Zebra">Zebra</option>
  </select>
  <br>

  <label for="bio">Biography</label>
  <textarea name="pet_bio" id="bio"></textarea>
  <br>

  <label for="owner-email">Owner's Email</label>
  <input name="pet_owner_email" id="owner-email" type="text" />
  <br>

  <button class="new-pet-submit-button" type="submit">
    Create new pet
  </button>

  <button class="Reset" type="reset">Reset</button>

  <form class='myform'>
    My form!
  </form>

</form>
<br>
<br>
<div class="card">
  <img src="images/desert.jpg" id="desert" class="card_image">
  <img src="images/person-avatar.jpg" class="person">
  <h1 class="title">Title goes here</h1>
  <h3 class="secondary">Secondary text</h3>
  <p class="card-body"> Greyhound divisively hello coldly wonderfully marginally far upon excluding.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You have set the width to be 600px. Did you mean it to be 100vw?

Comment: If you scrap the media queries you can set the form width to be 100vw. And as you don’t want the form ever to be wider than 600px you can also set max-width: 600px. max-width takes precedence over width.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a media query for that. Just use `max-width`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.myform {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-inline: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  
  /* here's where the magic happens */
  max-width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<form class = 'myform'>
  My form!
</form>
```

**Edited to add** If the behaviour when the screen is greater than 600px is the one you want then set the grid element to max-width: 600px and set the grid-template-columns to 1fr as below. I also made the margins to the left and right auto to centre the form alongside your card.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].style.fontSize = "6vw";
```

```css
.card {
  height: 335px;
  width: 344px;
  border: lightgrey;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  transition: box-shadow;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.card-body {
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #232f34;
}

.card_image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 194px;
}

.person {
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}

.title {
  display: inline;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 16px;
}

.secondary {
  color: #232f34;
  display: inline;
  padding: 16px;
}

/* got rid of the media query and added this */
form {
  margin-inline: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  max-width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="/pets">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input name="pet_name" id="name" type="text" />
  <br>
  <label for="type">Type</label>
  <select name="pet_type" id="type">
    <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="Hamster">Hamster</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
    <option value="Zebra">Zebra</option>
  </select>
  <br>

  <label for="bio">Biography</label>
  <textarea name="pet_bio" id="bio"></textarea>
  <br>

  <label for="owner-email">Owner's Email</label>
  <input name="pet_owner_email" id="owner-email" type="text" />
  <br>

  <button class="new-pet-submit-button" type="submit">
    Create new pet
  </button>

  <button class="Reset" type="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
<br>
<br>
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/46/200/300" id="desert" class="card_image">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/64/200/300" class="person">
  <h1 class="title">Title goes here</h1>
  <h3 class="secondary">Secondary text</h3>
  <p class="card-body"> Greyhound divisively hello coldly wonderfully marginally far upon excluding.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't have a div class for my for on the html side.  Should I add one first?

Comment: You can just use your form element. I'll update my answer to show this

Comment: It's still not working.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious.   https://imgur.com/a/1dWBh0Y

Comment: Rather than posting an image, can you send me the link to the actual code please and I'll pop on and have a look

Comment: C:\Users\Purpl\Documents\HTML ASSESSMENT\html-css-assessment-1.3\html-css-assessment\site.css    C:\Users\Purpl\Documents\HTML ASSESSMENT\html-css-assessment-1.3\html-css-assessment\index.html

Comment: Sorry, I meant can you put it on codepen.io or similar. I can't access your C drive.

Comment: Sorry!  https://codepen.io/UpsetSheepHerder/pen/poZEJWa   Thanks for the suggestion.  I've been looking for a site to do exactly this!

Comment: Just for the future, SO has its own sandbox system. Please use that rather than an external site. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I've updated your question with a code snippet and amended my answer fro you

Comment: @Adam   Thanks for the help on this, but the form is still not staying the width of the screen once the screen shrinks below 600px. 
https://www.loom.com/share/f788bb13eee24401aaf41984d34f7207

Comment: Can you pop a codepen of the code for that video as on Firefox and Chrome it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

To make a form element have a width of 600px when the window is wider than 600px, you can use a media query in your CSS:
This media query will apply the styles inside it only when the viewport width is greater than or equal to 600px.
To make the form element have a different width when the window is less than 600px wide, you can use another media query:

Comment: give some example code